# Auto change order status from pending to completed in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to change paid order status pending to completed.

CODE:

````
function wc_autocomplete_paid_orders( $order_status, $order_id ) {
    
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    if ( $order_status == 'pending' ) {
        return 'completed';
    }
    
    return $order_status;

} ```

THank you for the help.
````

Comment: When do you need this order status state transition to be executed?

Comment: @plamenNikolov yes when order is paid

Comment: This should happen automatically from the payment provider integration, what payment provider do you use and is it configured correctly?

Comment: i am using mercadopago (TEST MODE).

Comment: You need to check the configuration for this provider as implicitly changing the order from pending to completed is not a good idea. This should happen only when the order has been payed.

Comment: Yes i am paying order with test mode but still order status is going on Pending mode. is there any other way to change it to completed

Comment: Thank you for the help. i found it. With Stripe payment its working normally

Comment: You can change the order status from the WordPress Admin panel / WooCommerce / Orders then select the order and change it status to completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do this programatically as this is done from the payment providers that your WooCommerce is configured to use whet a successful order payment has been issued.

If in case you use a payment provider in sandbox mode or test mode that does not do this and you need to test the completed order status, you can do change this manually from the *WordPress* admin panel:

- `WordPress Admin / WooCommerce / Orders` - edit a `PENDING` oder and change it manually to `COMPLETE`.